# Split large dataframe in R and output into separate sheets in a single Excel workbook

Tags: r, dataframe, split, export-to-excel, openxlsx

Suppose I have the following dataframe in R and I am looking to split the dataframe into separate Excel sheets categorised by the Fruit column

```
+--------+-------+
| Fruit  | Price |
+--------+-------+
| Apple  |    12 |
| Apple  |    14 |
| Apple  |    15 |
| Orange |     2 |
| Orange |     4 |
| Orange |     6 |
| Pear   |     3 |
| Pear   |     6 |
| Pear   |     9 |
+--------+-------+
```

After splitting the dataframe into 3 separate dataframes (Apple, Orange and Pear), I intend to export each dataframe into a separate Excel sheets (named Apple, Orange and Pear) but stored within the same Excel workbook `Out.xlsx`. However, the below R code does not work. The output is an Excel workbook `Out.xlsx` with only a single sheet, Pear, containing the Pear dataframe.

```
library(openxlsx)
df <- read_excel("Export excel test.xlsx")
output <- split(df, df$Fruit)
for (i in 1:length(output)){write.xlsx(x = output[i],
file = "Out.xlsx", sheetName = names(output[i]),append = TRUE)}
```

Would anyone be able to help on this? My actual dataframe has over 4 million rows, hence I need to split the dataframe into separate sheets to circumvent Excel's row limitations

Comment: The `write.xlsx` function from the __openxlsx__ package doesn't have an `append` argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are using commands from the xlsx package.

The **xlsx** package also provides the `write.xlsx` function, which allows you to append to an existing workbook.

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(subset(iris, subset=Species=="setosa"), 
    file="iris.xlsx", sheetName = "setosa")

write.xlsx(subset(iris, subset=Species=="versicolor"), 
    file="iris.xlsx", sheetName = "versicolor", append=TRUE)

write.xlsx(subset(iris, subset=Species=="virginica"), 
    file="iris.xlsx", sheetName = "virginica", append=TRUE)
```

---

The **openxlsx** package does this slightly differently. Here I'll use a loop instead.

```
library(openxlsx)

output <- split(iris, iris$Species)

wb <- createWorkbook()

for (i in 1:length(output)) {
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetName=names(output[i]))
  writeData(wb, sheet=names(output[i]), x=output[[i]]) # Note [[]]
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "iris.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```